# SAPI is nil on cgilua.lua:93

Tags: lua, cgilua

I'm trying to install and configure cgilua on my server. I've installed Apache and lua (5.2.1.4) via apt-get and cgilua (5.2.1-1) via luarocks. on Apache, I've added the lua_mod using a2enmod. I've created a lua.conf file to associate lua-script to lua and lp files.

To test if everything was ok , I used this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua

cgilua = require "cgilua"

cgilua.htmlheader()  

if cgilua.QUERY.language == 'english' then
   greeting = 'Hello World!'
elseif cgilua.QUERY.language == 'portuguese' then
   greeting = 'Olá Mundo!'
else
   greeting = '[unknown language]'
end

cgilua.put('<html>')  
cgilua.put('<head>')
cgilua.put('  <title>'..greeting..'</title>')
cgilua.put('</head>')
cgilua.put('<body>')
cgilua.put('  <strong>'..greeting..'</strong>')
cgilua.put('</body>')
cgilua.put('</html>')
```

And I keep getting this error:

> [lua:error] [pid 14909] AH02613: Error loading
>   /var/www/html/lua/index.lua: /usr/local/share/lua/5.2/cgilua.lua:93:
>   attempt to index upvalue 'SAPI' (a nil value)

Can somebody shed some light on this issue?